# Powershell Progress Bar

Tags: powershell, progress-bar, powershell-2.0

I'm new to Powershell and am having a problem getting a progress bar to work with a foreach-object loop (If it is even possible)

Thanks to Chris below is what I have so far, my problem here is that the progress bar gets to a point and then I get error: The 101 argument is greater than the maximum allowed range of 100:

```
$FolderList = Get-Content C:\Folders.txt
$i = 0

foreach( $Folder in $FolderList )
{

Write-Host $Folder
Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse *.pdf | foreach-object{

$fileCount = (Get-ChildItem $Folder).Count
$i += 1
Write-Progress -Activity "Counting Files" -status "Searching...." -percentComplete (($i / $fileCount)*100)

$pdf = c:\pdftk.exe $_.FullName dump_data
$NumberOfPages = [regex]::match($pdf,'NumberOfPages: (\d+)').Groups[1].Value

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name = $_.Name
    FullName = $_.FullName
    NumberOfPages = $NumberOfPages 
     } 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Please post the script *with* the `Write-Progress` in it. IOW, show us what you've tried, and tell what the problem is. Or is your question "how do I put this chunk of code into that chunk of code?" In which case, again, please try what seems right, and post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my approach to the problem:

```
$i = 0
$pdfFiles = @()

#First, get the files and add them to a collection:
foreach ($folder in $FolderList){
    Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse *.pdf | %{$pdfFiles += $_}
}

#Measure the collection
$fileCount = ($pdfFiles | Measure-Object).Count

#Do work on the collection
$pdfFiles | foreach-object{
    $pdf = c:\pdftk.exe $_.FullName dump_data
    $NumberOfPages = [regex]::match($pdf,'NumberOfPages: (\d+)').Groups[1].Value
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        FullName = $_.FullName
        NumberOfPages = $NumberOfPages 
    }
    $i += 1
    Write-Progress -Activity "Counting Files" -status "Searching...." -percentComplete (($i / $fileCount)*100)
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the help. This has pointed me in the the right direction but because of the amount of objects withing each folder I was hoping to make the progress bar work within the foreach-object loop. The way you have showed me can sometimes make the progress bar look like it isn't moving until it moves to the next folder in the list. I have edited my question to reflect the change I made but came up with another problem.

Comment: Many Thanks Chris, I couldn't get it to work first of all but managed a workaround using the top part of your answer along with mine, and it worked fine. Just a bit messy! I decided to give it another go to clean things up and it worked so not sure what I did wrong first time around!! Thanks again!