# Powershell create temporary overlay area for data display

Tags: powershell, overlay, area

Progress bar and other processes like update-help
create overlay area to show data...

how can we use this mechanism (that already is there)
 
to show our data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756645/powershell-progress-bar)

Answer (score 0):

```
help Write-Progress
```

If you want to see what it looks like, try something like this and customize it to your liking. Setting the condition will be up to you to figure out for running whatever process it is that you would like to keep track of.

```
While ($true){Write-Progress -Activity "testing" -Status "In progress" -PercentComplete "1"}
```

Comment: Hi... that is the progress-bar (write-progress) machanism i mention,,, that overlay area above the console... I want to know how to use that funcionality to create my own "overlays",,,

Comment: I'm not sure how to create your own 'overlay' like you are referring to. Another option would be to create a custom gui which is certainly possible [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057024/powershell-loading-animation/44071896#44071896) but that would be a new separate window. You may have to compromise on the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I asked this because I liked the concept they adopted for the Progress-Bar overlay (it's like a DIV show/hide)... and since the code is implemented already... I thought maybe there is a way to use this functionality for our code... the GUI-Thing I already use it (WIN32 and WPF)... but for simple things this is like using a "Truck" when you need a "Skate" ;-)

Comment: I hear what you're saying, it would be nice if that overlay was more customizable. good luck on your search.